# Why is shred's -z option twice as slow?

Tags: shred

I'm using `shred` to wipe a partition, and did some speed testing. My results were, in seconds:

```
 6.4  using /dev/zero as the data source
 6.5  shred's default raondom implementation
12.9  using shred's `-z` option
```

Why is `-z` twice as slow? Here is the detail:

```
# time shred -z -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1
shred -z -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1  0.14s user 0.05s system 1% cpu 12.919 total

# time shred    -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1
shred -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1  0.14s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 6.509 total

# time shred --random-source=/dev/zero   -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1
shred --random-source=/dev/zero -s 256M -n 1 /dev/sdc1  0.00s user 0.06s system 0% cpu 6.419 total
```

(I am using Linux Mint 20 on an external USB 2.0 magnetic drive formatted as ExFAT.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's doing two passes. One random pass followed by one zero pass.

If you want `shred` to zero and nothing else, it's `shred -n 0 -z`.

Add `-v` for verbosity and you'll see.

Comment: It's also worth noting that on some systems doing `-n 0 -z` is much faster than doing `-n 1`.